# Convert multiple characters vectors to factors on a tibble

Tags: r, parsing, tibble

I used read_csv() to import a file into R. Now I wish to convert various character vectors to factors. I used this code and it worked fine.

```
library(readr)
library(tibble)
activos_dic_2017$DESCRI_RIESGO <- parse_factor(activos_dic_2017$DESCRI_RIESGO, 
                                            unique(activos_dic_2017$DESCRI_RIESGO))
```

It´s basically this :

```
tibble_data$column_name <- parse_factor(tibble_data$column_name, 
                                        unique(tibble_data$column_name))
```

I tried implementing that code using a for loop, where i already knew the column number i wanted to convert as factors

```
for(i in c(5, 6, 8) ){

  tibble_data[i] <- parse_factor(tibble_data[i], 
                                  unique(tibble_data[i]))


}
```

however I got the following error

```
Error in parse_vector_(x, collector, na = na, locale_ = locale) : 
Not compatible with STRSXP: [type=list].
```

How do i convert multiple character vectors to factors?

Comment: `table%>%mutate_at(vars(c(5,6,8)),funs(factor(.,unique(.))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the double brackets instead.

```
for(i in c(5, 6, 8) ){

  tibble_data[[i]] <- parse_factor(tibble_data[[i]], 
                                   unique(tibble_data[[i]])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your framework:

```
ref <- c(5, 6, 8)

for(i in 1:length(ref) ){

  tibble_data[, ref[i] ] <- parse_factor(tibble_data[, ref[i] ], 
                                         unique(tibble_data[, ref[i] ]))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in `?parse_factor` one can read:

> **levels**
>   Character vector providing set of allowed levels. if NULL,
>   will generate levels based on the unique values of x, ordered by order
>   of appearance in x.

So you can just set the second argument to `NULL`.

I'd then use `purr::modify_at` to conveniently modify only a given set of items:

```
library(purrr)
iris2 <- modify_at(head(iris),c(2,4),parse_factor,NULL)
str(iris2)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4
# $ Sepal.Width : Factor w/ 6 levels "3.5","3","3.2",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
# $ Petal.Width : Factor w/ 2 levels "0.2","0.4": 1 1 1 1 1 2
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1
```